# Find Consecutive Rows in Dataframe where Column Values are Within a Set Range

Tags: pandas

With the dataframe below i need to subset for each Member to find all rows where:

1. the Donation is within 20% (either less than or greater than) of a preceding Donation;
2. there are at least 4 subsequent Donations that meet the criteria in 1 (so return 5 rows in total).

To do this i need to look at the Donation in each row (let's call it "Original Donation") then check the immediately following rows for each Member to see if the Donation in those rows is within 20% of the Original Donation.

Is this possible without creating multiple helper columns using shift()?

Here's some sample data and the desired result:

| Date | Member | Donation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/02/2023 | 1 | 2 |
| 12/02/2023 | 1 | 2 |
| 19/02/2023 | 1 | 5 |
| 26/02/2023 | 1 | 2 |
| 05/03/2023 | 1 | 1.5 |
| 12/03/2023 | 1 | 2 |
| 19/03/2023 | 1 | 5 |
| 26/03/2023 | 1 | 5 |
| 05/02/2023 | 2 | 5 |
| 12/02/2023 | 2 | 5 |
| 19/02/2023 | 2 | 4.5 |
| 26/02/2023 | 2 | 5.1 |
| 05/03/2023 | 2 | 3 |
| 12/03/2023 | 2 | 3 |
| 19/03/2023 | 2 | 5 |
| 26/03/2023 | 2 | 5 |
| 05/02/2023 | 3 | 10 |
| 12/02/2023 | 3 | 11 |
| 19/02/2023 | 3 | 11 |
| 26/02/2023 | 3 | 12 |
| 05/03/2023 | 3 | 5 |
| 12/03/2023 | 3 | 10 |
| 19/03/2023 | 3 | 9 |
| 26/03/2023 | 3 | 9 |

Result:

| Date | Member | Donation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/02/2023 | 2 | 5 |
| 12/02/2023 | 2 | 5 |
| 19/02/2023 | 2 | 4.5 |
| 26/02/2023 | 2 | 5.1 |
| 05/02/2023 | 3 | 10 |
| 12/02/2023 | 3 | 11 |
| 19/02/2023 | 3 | 11 |
| 26/02/2023 | 3 | 12 |

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following this completely but this seems to be close to what you want:

- isolate the 'Original Donations' into a dictionary

  OriginalDonationdf = df.groupby(['Member'])['Donation'].agg(['first'])

  OriginalDonation = OriginalDonationdf.to_dict().get('first')
- filter the dataframe by mapping that

  df[abs(df['Donation'] - df['Member'].map(OriginalDonation)) < df['Member'].map(OriginalDonation) * 0.2]
- results in:

|  | Date | Member | Donation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 05/02/2023 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 12/02/2023 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 26/02/2023 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 12/03/2023 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 05/02/2023 | 2 | 5 |
| 9 | 12/02/2023 | 2 | 5 |
| 10 | 19/02/2023 | 2 | 4.5 |
| 11 | 26/02/2023 | 2 | 5.1 |
| 14 | 19/03/2023 | 2 | 5 |
| 15 | 26/03/2023 | 2 | 5 |
| 16 | 05/02/2023 | 3 | 10 |
| 17 | 12/02/2023 | 3 | 11 |
| 18 | 19/02/2023 | 3 | 11 |
| 21 | 12/03/2023 | 3 | 10 |
| 22 | 19/03/2023 | 3 | 9 |
| 23 | 26/03/2023 | 3 | 9 |